# python for loop with if loop and output a file

Tags: python

my first time writing python script. I had read through many questions and answers in stack overflow, but still didn't figure out where I got wrong in my code. Probably I could ask for help?

I have a file file.txt as below, with uncertain number of column in each line. "\t" is the tab delimiter

$ head file.txt

```
AA:d23\tBB:4r3w\tCC:e5t
BB:435\tCC:w4w
AA:w4r\tCC:2342
AA:34534\tBB:e5\tCC:7uf
BB:e4t4
```

I would like to turn it into a data_frame like .txt file, which has three columns in each row by adding NA for the missing column. Also, I would like to eliminate the rows that only have one entry (e.g. only AA or only BB or only CC). So expected output like below:

```
AA:d23\tBB:4r3w\tCC:e5t
AA:NA\tBB:435\tCC:w4w
AA:w4r\tBB:NA\tCC:2342
AA:34534\tBB:e5\tCC:7uf
#(the 5th line is omitted here because it only has one entry)
```

After studying many examples on the forum,I mimicked some codes, and wrote my own code as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#into_data.py
import csv
import fileinput

def into_data(a_file):
  output=[]
  for row in a_file:
     if "AA:" in row and "BB:" in row and "CC:" in row:
        output.append(row)
     elif "AA:" not in row and "BB:" in row and "CC:" in row:
        output.append("AA:NA" + row)
     elif "AA:" in row and "BB:" not in row and "CC:" in row:
        output.append(row.split("\t")[0] + "CB:NA" + row.split("\t")[1])
     elif "AA:" in row and "BB:" in row and "CC:" not in row:
        output.append(row + "CC:NA")


reader = csv.reader(fileinput.input(), delimiter="\t")
print(into_data(reader))
```

#outside python script

```
python3 into_data.py file.txt > output.txt
```

But I get "None" in my output.txt. I don't really understand why. Could you please be so kind to point my error out? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: your function doesnt return anything

Comment: Also note: since `a_file` is a `csv.reader` each row is a list and there is no need to use `split`.

Comment: to be specific: if you don't return anything Python will return None automatically.

Comment: Where do you assign `fileinput`?

Comment: @KarolMilewczyk Thanks for pointing it out! I thought probably I should use a return, but I'm not sure what to return...

Comment: The last row in the file is missing both `AA:` and `CC:`, none of the `if` conditions handle that.

Comment: Actually, none of the conditions match anything. `row` will be a list like `['AA:d23', 'BB:4r3w', 'CC:e5t']`. `AA:`, `BB:`, and `CC:` are prefixes of the list elements, but `in` checks for an exact match with a list element.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! For the row missing two fields, I will eliminate it in the final output.  Thanks also for pointing out the matching part. I saw some post with the this matching pattern by fields, and thought probably it will work as well in rows. How could I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty straight forward way that should handle all cases.

```
# a_file is a csv.reader
def into_data(a_file):
    output = []
    for row in a_file:
        if len(row) <= 1: continue
        if not row[0].startswith("AA"):
            row.insert(0, "AA:NA")
        if not row[1].startswith("BB"):
            row.insert(1, "BB:NA")
        if len(row) < 3:
            row.append("CC:NA")
        output.append(row)
    return output
```

This creates a list of lists. If you want a list of strings, change the line `output.append(row)` to

```
output.append('\t'.join(row))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one is easy and simple for me! One question I have is why do we use a three `if` but not three `elif`? Are they different? Thanks!

Comment: Because you want all 3 conditions checked . For example, if the string only has "AA" you want the "BB" _and_ the "CC" cases to run. In `if/elif/else` only _one_ condition is run.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again. I don't know how but get a one line string like `['AA:d23\tBB:4r3w\tCC:e5t', 'AA:NA\tBB:435\tCC:w4w', (...omit other parts)]` (all the rows are separated by comma). I used the `output.append('\t'.join(row))` version. I'm trying to see why, but have no success. Could you please give me some hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can join all the strings in output with `return (','.join(output))`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Sorry,  I didn't express myself clearly. I mean, I used `output.append('\t'.join(row))`, but got a one line string like this `['AA:d23\tBB:4r3w\tCC:e5t', 'AA:NA\tBB:435\tCC:w4w', (...omit other parts)]`. I don't know why. I can't also simply replace the `,` and `[]` into nothing by `sed` command to get a clean table as in the question.

Comment: Then maybe you want `return ('\n'.join(output))`

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't have a return statement. Therefore it defaults to returning `None`.

You need to return the `output` at the end of the function like this:

```
def into_data(a_file):
  output=[]
  for row in a_file:
     if "AA:" in row and "BB:" in row and "CC:" in row:
        output.append(row)
     elif "AA:" not in row and "BB:" in row and "CC:" in row:
        output.append("AA:NA" + row)
     elif "AA:" in row and "BB:" not in row and "CC:" in row:
        output.append(row.split("\t")[0] + "CB:NA" + row.split("\t")[1])
     elif "AA:" in row and "BB:" in row and "CC:" not in row:
        output.append(row + "CC:NA")
  return output
```

To edit the rows as you specify, you can try this:

```
def into_data(a_file):
  output = []
  for row in a_file:
     if len(row) <= 1:
         continue
     if "AA:" not in row[0]:
        row.insert(0, "AA:NA")
     if "BB:" not in row[1]:
        row.insert(1, "BB:NA")
     if len(row) < 3:
        row.insert(2, "CC:NA")
     output.append(row)
  return output
```

Comment: I get only [] in the output file...

Comment: @zzz See my comments above -- your whole algorithm is wrong.

Comment: @zzz so your body of for loop needs fixes, you get value of output declared on top of the function, which is empty list.

Comment: Oh I saw your comments above, thinking how to correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Nice one as well!

Answer (score 1):

Since you evoke dataframes/[**`pandas`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html), here is a proposition :

###### # Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None, sep=r'\\t', engine='python')

m = df.notnull().sum(axis=1).eq(1)
#does the row has a single entry ?

df = df.loc[~m]

out = (df.stack().reset_index(name='val')
   .assign(col=lambda x: x['val'].str.slice(0,2))
   .pivot(index='level_0', columns='col', values='val')
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)

out[:] = np.where(out.isna(), [out.columns + ':NA'], out)

out.columns = df.columns

out.to_csv('final.txt', sep='\t', header=None, index=False)
```

###### # Output :

```
print(out)

          0        1        2
0    AA:d23  BB:4r3w   CC:e5t
1     AA:NA   BB:435   CC:w4w
2    AA:w4r    BB:NA  CC:2342
3  AA:34534    BB:e5   CC:7uf
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I haven't used pandas before, and will look up a bit the functions you use here. Thanks a lot again!